# How run python web scraper on another windows machines without python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Right now I’m writing a web scraper in Python, I’m a freelancer and I received this order.

The main part of the question is what do I need to do with my code so that the person who receives it can just run it and it will work (in Windows OS). With the condition that I myself will enter everything he needs.

Let's take into account that this person wants to get a finished product, and he doesn't understand programming at all.

Thank you for your attention

I want to try to compile my code in .exe, but what should I do with the libraries that are used?

Comment: The most common way is to ship python with the application. What do you mean by "compile my code in .exe"? Python cant be compiled like C++ for instance.

Comment: [auto py to exe](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), but depending on what you use for scraping this may or may not work.

Comment: i use beautifulsoup4

Comment: or another way I can host my web scraper on the server and give access, will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way could be to use [`pyinstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/). Just run `pyinstaller my_program.py` and your program will be in the `dist` folder as an `exe` file.